# Python axis scaling in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axes

I am trying to make my plots a bit more readable and have come across a feature where the axes are automatically scaled by factors of tens (so instead of the y axis reading 0.00000005, 0.00000007, 0.00000009, it reads 0.5,0.7,0.9 and then says 1e-7 at the top of the axis). However some of my plots don't scale the axes automatically, and I would like to get advise of how to do that manually.

I have found threads on manually setting the tick marks, however I haven't been able to find threads on scaling only.

I can't imbed pictures but here is a link to a picture of what I would like to do: [Ideal y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idVRo.png) and here's link to a picture of what I want to avoid: [Current y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNGmT.png).

I'm using seaborn formatting and matplotlib for plots and my code looks like this:

```
plt.plot(x_j_n,y_j_n, label='Scanning i negativ retning', color='grey', ls='dashed')
plt.plot(x_j_p,y_j_p, label='Scanning i positiv retning', color='black', ls='dashed')
plt.errorbar(x_j_n,y_j_n, yerr=std_j_n, fmt='o', color='black', mfc='white', label = 'Usikkerhed')
plt.errorbar(x_j_p,y_j_p, yerr=std_j_p, fmt='o', color='grey', mfc='white', label = 'Usikkerhed')
plt.ylabel('Målt spænding i volt (V)')
plt.xlabel('Påtrykt felt i tesla (T)')
plt.legend()
plt.show;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47730817/4551984 should help.

Answer (score 0):

Set the y axis to scientific:

```
plt.gca().yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(True)
```

For example:

```
x = [1100000,2200000,3300000]
y = [1100000,2200000,3300000]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gca().xaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
plt.gca().yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_scientific(True)
plt.show()
```

will give:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to have any effect on my plot. Should I do more than just add the one line?

Comment: It was supposed to be just that line. Does it throw any error message?

Comment: No, it just doesn't alter anything

Comment: fyi, more concise function: `plt.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='sci')`